# How to prevent Speech.Framework iOS from accessing contact list?

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, contacts, speech

I am using speech framework to do speech to text implementation. 
I also have contact permission for login feature.
Speech framework working perfectly fine like below only little bit problem left.

**for example:**

My voice -> *"Hi Andy"*

Speech to Text -> *"Hi Andy Deadman"*
Even-though i didn't say *Deadman*.

**Expected:**

Speech to Text -> *"Hi Andy"*

So, we found out that if we have some contact list in our phone with phonetic name it recognized and replace it automatically.

is it possible to prevent speech.framework from accessing that information?

Comment: to disable an object from doing something is not a proper English use.  You can say that you want to stop speech.framework from accessing that piece of information or to prevent it from accessing that piece of information.

Comment: @ElTomato Thanks, sorry about that. I mean to prevent from accessing the contact information :)